# Mongoose: populate after query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to i populate the query result after query in mongoose like this:

```
users
        .find({name:"doejohn"})
        .skip(3)
        .limit(9)
        .exec((err,user) => {
            user // result
                .populate("tweets")
                .exec(callback)
})
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this :

```
users.findOne({username:"doejohn"})
        .skip(3)
        .populate("tweets")
        .exec((err,user) => {})
```

`.limit(9)` is useless, because you're using `.findOne()`

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
users.findOne({username:"doejohn"})
    .skip(3)
    .populate("tweets"," Columns name ")
    .exec((err,user) => {})
```

you can read the docs of populate in mongoose [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: this is only populate a first result.not others: users.find({username:"doejohn"})                                                                      
    .skip(3)                                                                                                                                                                   .limit(9)  
    .populate("tweets")
    .exec((err,user) => {})

Comment: Of course it's only populating one result. You're using `.findOne()`. Find ONE. So it will return ONE document.